# Store User Date EF MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, entity-framework-4

Am trying to understand problem in how to store every user date like ( comments ,questions,....etc )  ... or when having list of requernmints and we need to store each user checklist of the requirement separately.... i though of the following example :

here an example :

I have list of Questions related to Subject. Then  Student will be able to chose subject and view list of the question and answer them.
teacher then can come and see the questions answered for every students in separate view .

How to design the model and the view  so that I will be  able to store each student Answers!! so teacher can come then and  see view  students list under his subject and can chose  a student to  check his answer of the question....

Here my model classes and relations,I don't know the logic of design it .... please guide me!

I hope I explained well

```
 public class  Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int SubjectID { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Questions>  Questions { get; set; } ; 

}

 public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Subjects> Subjects { get; set; } ; 

}
   public class Students
  {
    [Key]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Answer>  Answer{ get; set; } ; 
  }

  public class Questions 
   {
    [Key]
    public int QuestionsID { get; set; }
    public string TheQuestion { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
  }

  public class Answer 
  {
    [Key]
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
    public string TheAnswer  { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

   }
```

Comment: I would have to say you are asking for a lot.  How about you tell us what thing you would like to accomplish first instead of everything you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need to understand the logic of design my model and view, I know the basic functions of listing the Questions..but then I need "user A" to answer the questions and when "user B" come will see the same list with no answer and  he can answer . Teachers then can see the answer of each one.